# iOS using blend modes with cgcontext

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm using CGContextSetBlendMode to try color blend a gradient (stored in `gradient`) with several shapes (black with some transparency). I attached an image with the result. It's easy to see what is going wrong. Somehow artifacts show up.

what I try to do seems to work partially, but I'm not sure if my approach is correct. I first draw the shapes, then set the blend mode of the context and then draw my gradient.

Also weird is that when I for example use `kCGBlendModeColorBurn` instead of `kCGBlendModeColor` the artifacts don't show up. I'm also not drawing anything else in the layer.

I can't really get a hold on how the blend modes work. I can't find any good documentation.

```
CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(60,170,200,200);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGRect rectangle2 = CGRectMake(40,120,100,100);
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectangle2);
CGContextFillPath(context);

CGContextSetBlendMode( context, kCGBlendModeColor);

CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
```

[image: Example of the artifacts showing up using kCGBlendModeColor]

Comment: I have used blend mode in cgcontext  . You can refer here and experiment on it :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497703/union-uibezierpaths-rather-than-apend-path/41179791#41179791