# Combining two or more SCNGeometries

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, scenekit

I made this method to grab a UIImage and turn it into a 3D model. However that means I add in a whole lot of nodes.. I was thinking maybe it could be optimized by adding all the geometries into a single node. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Here's the code

```
static inline SCNNode* S2NNode(const UIImage* sprite) {
  SCNNode *spriteNode = [SCNNode node];
  CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(sprite.CGImage));
  const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
  for (int x = 0; x < sprite.size.width; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y < sprite.size.height; y++)
    {
      int pixelInfo = ((sprite.size.width * y) + x) * 4;
      UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
      if (alpha > 3)
      {
        UInt8 red   = data[pixelInfo];
        UInt8 green = data[pixelInfo + 1];
        UInt8 blue  = data[pixelInfo + 2];
        UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];
        SCNNode *pixel = [SCNNode node];
        pixel.geometry = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:1.001 height:1.001 length:1.001 chamferRadius:0];
        pixel.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = color;
        pixel.position = SCNVector3Make(x - sprite.size.width / 2.0,
                                        y - sprite.size.height / 2.0,
                                        0);
        [spriteNode addChildNode:pixel];
      }
    }
  }
  CFRelease(pixelData);
  //The image is upside down and I have no idea why.
  spriteNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1, 0, 0, M_PI);
  return spriteNode;
}
```

Comment: This code is supposed to be used for small sprites

Comment: Try not to use an image over CGSizeMake(100,100)

Comment: what are you trying to do? Making a cube for each pixel of an image is indeed not a good for performance. Depending on what you want to achieve, there might be other solutions.

Comment: I'd like to have a single geometry for all these cubes I placed. So I was wondering if there was a way to add all these geometries together so maybe that would help performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer addresses the question originally asked — how to merge geometries. However, merging geometries doesn't seem to be the solution to your actual problem — how to get a pixelated "sprite" with some thickness, with decent performance. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821031/957768) for that.

---

The `SCNNode` method [`flattenedClone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/index.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/SCNNode/flattenedClone) will combine all the geometries of a node's children into a single node with a single geometry. That'll cut down on scene processing overhead and render in a single OpenGL draw call... But it also will make the cubes not independently movable and all share the same material, so they won't be different colors. Moreover, depending on how you want your cubes arranged, you're probably pushing more vertex data than you need to the GPU, which can still hurt your performance.

Depending on just what kind of effect you're going for, there are probably better solutions.

Comment: You were right about removing the ability to move the squares independently. The colors stayed the same. However it's still just as intensive on the GPU. How would I create vertex data from my SCNNode?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do with it. Ask another question or edit your original question with a description of your end goal — the steps to get there might not be wait you think.

Comment: the result you get here is just another box. But SceneKit is not smart enough to detect that and the number of vertices stays the same. Can you not use a single box onto which you map your texture with `SCNFilterModeNone` to achieve the *pixelate* effect ?

Comment: Your suggestion results in this. http://i.imgur.com/OUSq8E2.png
What I'm looking for is. http://i.imgur.com/YgkILT2.png
However my method uses up a lot of memory.

Comment: Ah, so what you're looking for is a "pixelated" shape with some thickness? Then ditch the cubes and use `SCNShape`. I'll post another answer with more detail on that shortly.

Answer (score 3):

Posting a separate answer because your comments have shown that what you're actually looking for isn't quite what you're asking about — I'm leaving the other answer around because it answers the question as originally asked, even if it doesn't solve your problem.

---

So, it sounds like what you really need is not a collection of cubes, each independently movable and each with its own color, but rather the extrusion of a 2D shape into 3D — specifically, the shape formed by the non-transparent pixels of an image:

[image: chunky sprite]

In that case, making a bunch of cubes will indeed hurt your performance — and your rendering results, too. Check out this detail (from a version that uses the lots-of-cubes method):

[image: artifacts]

Those little white dots come from rounding errors where two cubes meet. The problem here — whether you use `flattenedClone` or not — is that the geometry data being pushed to the GPU describes a whole darn lot of polygons that are either invisible (because they're between two cubes) or irrelevant (because the shared face of two adjacent cubes could just as well be a single polygon). Here's the performance gauge from my test of the lots-of-cubes method:

[image: 408 draws, 4.9K polygons, 14.7K vertices]

That's 408 draws, 4.9K polygons, 14.7K vertices. Spinning that model on an iPad Air gets 14 frames per second — yuck.

You can make an extruded shape from a Bézier path using the [`SCNShape`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShape_Class/index.html) class. The trick to that is making the simplest possible path from the shape of your non-transparent pixels. (You want the path that makes the outline of the shape, not the union of a bunch of square paths for each pixel — otherwise you're right back to the cubes problem.)

That's a nontrivial bit of computational geometry, but [there are solutions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23497703/957768). And there are external tools that can do the tracing for you offline (most of them designed for making sprite-based physics bodies for SpriteKit back before that became a SpriteKit feature in iOS 8 / OS X 10.10): [here's one](https://www.codeandweb.com/physicseditor).

Once you have the path, you can make a `SCNShape` from it, texture-map your image as onto the front of the shape (and the back, too, if you like), and use a flat color for the sides:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sprite"];
UIBezierPath *path = PathFromImage(image); // Make or load your path here
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:[SCNShape shapeWithPath:path extrusionDepth:1]];
SCNMaterial *face = [SCNMaterial material];
face.diffuse.contents = image;
face.diffuse.magnificationFilter = SCNFilterModeNone;
SCNMaterial *side = [SCNMaterial material];
side.diffuse.contents = [UIColor blackColor];
side.specular.contents = [UIColor whiteColor];
node.geometry.materials = @[ face, side, side ];
```

Here's the gauge using an `SCNShape` instead:

[image: 3 draws, 276 polygons, 828 vertices]

We've cut the numbers by two orders of magnitude, and correspondingly the framerate is much better — I can't get it to drop below 60 fps when the model is spinning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain all of this to me. I'm trying to rework your answer, but I'm confused on how I use the tool you provided me to create a path depending on what image I pass in as a parameter?

Comment: It doesn't — to make a path from an arbitrary image is a hairy problem. If you have specific images you want to do this for, use a tool like the one I linked to create specific paths for each.

Comment: Also, that particular tool doesn't output `UIBezierPath` code, but it does output a list of points you can use for constructing your own code.

Comment: In that case, you'll need your own code (or a library) that does the same thing as that tool — as noted, there are solutions to that problem out there. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23497703/957768) to get started.

Comment: I added another question. Hopefully I was more articulate. In that one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28824103/convert-an-image-to-a-scenekit-node