# Fill Path on Intersecting UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Any idea on how to fill all the paths in here. What is currently happening is that I draw a rectangle path on my view then add small circles in between but it seems that if the circle and rectangle intersects, the white fill color is showing. What I would want is show still the gradient layer. Any help? My current code is below. [image]

```
    func addGradientLayer() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds

        let startColor = UIColor.create(withHexOrName: OurPayStatesViewUX.GradientColorStart)
        let endColor = UIColor.create(withHexOrName: OurPayStatesViewUX.GradientColorEnd)

        gradientLayer.colors = [startColor.CGColor, endColor.CGColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
        layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, atIndex: 0)
    }

    func createOverlay(view: UIView, circleLocations: [CGPoint]) {

        maskLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()

        let radius: CGFloat = view.frame.height/2
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.size.width, height: view.bounds.size.height), cornerRadius: 0)

        for i in circleLocations {
            // Create a circle path in each of the state views
            let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: i.x, y: i.y, width: 2 * radius, height: 2 * radius), cornerRadius: radius)
            path.appendPath(circlePath)
        }

        let rect = createRectangle(startPointX: 0, endPointX: view.bounds.size.width)
        path.appendPath(rect)

        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

        let fillLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        fillLayer.path = path.CGPath
        fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
        fillLayer.fillColor = backgroundColor?.CGColor ?? UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        fillLayer.opacity = 1

        maskLayer = fillLayer
        layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
    }

    func createRectangle(startPointX startPointX: CGFloat, endPointX: CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath {
        let rectHeight: CGFloat = 6
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: startPointX, y: frame.height/2 - rectHeight/2, width: endPointX - startPointX, height: rectHeight))

        return path
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you do **not** use evenOdd fill rule?

Comment: it seems that toggling path.usesEvenOddFillRule does nothing on my case

Comment: did you remove `fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd` as well?
In your case, `path.usesEventOddFillRule` does nothing anyway. It's only relevant when you do CG draws using the path object. (e.g. `path.fill()`)

Comment: removing fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd would just make the whole view white.

Comment: leave even odd disabled and change `let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:...)` to `let path = UIBezierPath()`

Comment: There is a library that can do what you want -- search for `VectorBoolean`. Alternatively, for something like the image you've shown, I'd think it would be fairly simple to draw the circles on a rectangle, and then use the resulting as a mask (as opposed to trying to get the paths to join properly). You may also want to look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23497703/union-uibezierpaths-rather-than-apend-path