# Swift Combine and reverse UIBezierPaths

Tags: swift, uikit, uibezierpath, cgpath

The problem I am facing is reversing subpaths. Take this example:

```swift
let circlePaths: [UIBezierPath] = ...
let rectanglePath: UIBezierPath = ... // a rectangle

let totalPath: UIBezierPath = .init()
for path in circlePaths {
  totalPath.append(path)
}
rectanglePath.append(totalPath)
```

It should look like this:

[image: circle image]

Now ideally I want to cut out all the circles using

```
bezierPath.append(totalPath.reversing())
```

However the effect is not as expected. I expect the two circles to make up a path and this one is reversed, however in reality both circle paths are reversed, which causes the intersection to be part of the path (`reversing()` twice has no effect). I'd like to combine the circle paths into one with the intersection not being present but as part of the path. I want the smaller circle to "extend" the larger circle as a path.

Any idea how I would do it?

Edit 1: Here is an image how the resulting path should look like.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51555256/1801544 ? ClippingBezier external lib might be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

If you need to actually create a single path as the combination / union of your multiple paths, you may want to look at one of the libraries that are out there.

However, if you only need that **visual output**, this might be a usable approach.

- Create 3 paths -- outer rect, large circle, small circle.
- Stroke and Fill the outer rect path
- Stroke both circle paths
- Fill both circle paths

An example `UIView` class:

```
class FakeUnionUIBezierPaths : UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        // yellow line width
        let lWidth: CGFloat = 8
        
        // paths are stroked on the center, so
        // use one-half the line width to adjust ediges
        let hWidth: CGFloat = lWidth * 0.5
        
        // border / outer rect, inset by one-half line width
        let dRect: CGRect = rect.insetBy(dx: hWidth, dy: hWidth)
        
        // first circle
        //  full-height
        //  aligned to left edge
        var c1Rect: CGRect = dRect
        c1Rect.size.width = c1Rect.height
        
        // second circle
        //  half-height
        //  aligned to right edge
        var c2Rect: CGRect = dRect
        c2Rect.size.height *= 0.5
        c2Rect.size.width = c2Rect.height
        c2Rect.origin.x = dRect.width - c2Rect.width + hWidth
        c2Rect.origin.y = dRect.height * 0.25
        
        let pRect: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: dRect)
        let p1: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: c1Rect)
        let p2: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: c2Rect)
        
        UIColor.yellow.setStroke()
        UIColor.blue.setFill()

        // same line-width for all three paths
        [pRect, p1, p2].forEach { p in
            p.lineWidth = lWidth
        }
        
        // stroke and fill the border / outer rect
        pRect.stroke()
        pRect.fill()

        // stroke both circle paths
        p1.stroke()
        p2.stroke()
        
        // fill both circle paths
        p1.fill()
        p2.fill()
        
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]